# How is encoded data read from a columnar database e.g. RLE encoded data in Vertica?

Tags: database, vertica, columnstore

In the following table when Data in Dept field is encoded and stored, how does the Dept with value 10 know it has Age value of 38.

### ID Dept Age

### 1 10 60

### 2 10 38

### 3 10 49

For a row store i understand that i check for ID 2 and i get the data for entire row.

But i am not able to wrap my head around as to how the data is retrieved for ID 2 when its in columnar store and Dept information is in encoded form.

Could you please help me understand if i am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's consider the columnar data in unencoded form:

`ID` with value 2 is the second element in the column, so to get the `Dept` and `Age` all that needs to be done is take their second element.

Now in encoded (compressed) form, you could look at the data in ranges. For example `Dept` could be encoded as 3*10, thus range 1-3 having a value of 10. To retrieve the second element in `Dept`, the database has to look for the range that holds the second element. That would be the range 1-3 which has a value of 10.

Or looked at in another way: to get `Dept` at position 4 in a sequential way, the system would see there is a group of 3 elements compacted into 1 value, so the item after that group (which could be a new group of identical values) would contain the value for the fourth element.

To speed things up, the system would of course keep an index with positions to be able to jump (semi)directly to the value of a certain range (and those ranges/groups would be stored in blocks, say 1-8 kB each - in a [B+ Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) for example, especially when values need to be inserted later).

Another possibility would be to store those groups (range values with their rle prefix) in blocks, keep track of the first and (or only) last item index of each block, and decompress the block that contains the value for the index we're looking for. Then calculate the offset for the item in that decompressed block. This would depend on the type of compression used to store the data in that block.

---

On the other hand, in most cases we don't need all the data from a record, and that's why column based data stores are so interesting.

Let's consider a table with 1 billion records, 200 bytes each (string data etc.) and a system with 10 GB free RAM (I took the number of records big enough so the table won't fit in memory). So that's 200 GB of data.

Now let's say we want the total sum of a certain column (a 4 byte integer column). To calculate the sum on a record based table, we have to read the value every 200 bytes, and since data is read from disk in 4kB pages we have to read the full 200GB. On a normal disk at 100MB/sec that would take 2000 seconds.

If we have our data separated in columns, even with uncompressed data we would only have to read 4GB of data (which could already be in memory). If the column is compressed, say 10:1, that would only be 400MB. If the data is sparse (say a lot of zero or null values) that would be even less. Also to sum a range of 100 identical values all that needs to be done is 100*value instead of reading 100*200 bytes from disk, or even skip that range if they are zero.

There is also an extra speed gain because all that data (all values being close together) would be accessed from the L1 CPU cache, which is a lot faster than accessing main memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to understand here ! Data representation has nothing to do with how data is written to your FS by Vertica.

Encoding is used to optimize data fetch process.

As for the row based vs columnar based, The concept of ROWKEY(internal database) works the same for both
 The ROWKEY is maintained by your db engine and "it works in mysterious ways" :)

I short Encoding is for write & read , you are not going to see encoded binary code, you are going to see a representation of the encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Vertica uses many different [encoding types](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/encoding-type.htm). RLE is just one of the possible options (good for low cardinality, **sorted** columns). Please keep in mind that some encoding can reduce storage size (a lot) but increase CPU usage.

**Second**: if you want to see "RLE in action" please check [this other section](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/PhysicalSchema/ChoosingSortOrderBestPractices.htm) of the manual providing a clear and concise explanation (I think pictures help a lot).

**Third**: in your sample table picking the right encoding - in terms of storage - is quite easy.  For example, if the first two column are sorted I'd say COMMONDELTA_COMP for the first column and RLE for the second one. However - generally speaking - when you have lot of data you might want to use Vertica's Database Designer to automatically pick the "right" encoding...